# RSS feed for Wikipedia's The Signpost?

Tags: notifications, rss, wikipedia, feedburner

Since June this year, [the RSS feed I was using](http://www.wikipediasignpost.com/blog/?feed=rss2) to get notified about new issues of [The Signpost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Signpost/About) is not updated anymore. I have been searching for alternative RSS feeds but can't find any. Converting [their Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/wikisignpost) to RSS is not an option, because they publish other content (for instance scoops) on Twitter.

Is there a way to get Signpost issues notifications as an RSS feed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the Signpost by watching the page [Wikipedia:Wikipedia Signpost/Issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aWikipedia_Signpost/Issue). It's updated whenever a new issue of the Signpost is published. And that also means you can use the Atom feed for the history of that page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:Wikipedia_Signpost/Issue&feed=atom&action=history

(Alternatively use `feed=rss` in the URL if you really want RSS.)

Answer (score 0):

A new RSS feed is now maintained:

http://signpost.yuvi.in/feed